# rails best way to abstract deep object literal data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code like this in my controller:

```ruby
def home
  @mainImage = []
  @mainImage.push(
    {:breakpoint => 1024, 
     :src => i_path('pages/home-d.jpg'),
     :src_2x => i_path('pages/home-d_2x.jpg')}
  )
  @mainImage.push(
    {:breakpoint => 768, 
     :src => i_path('pages/home-t.jpg'), 
     :src_2x => i_path('pages/home-t_2x.jpg')}
  )
  @mainImage.push(
    {:breakpoint => 320, 
     :src => i_path('pages/home-m.jpg'), 
     :src_2x => i_path('pages/home-m_2x.jpg')}
  )
  @alt = 'An image description'
  @defaultImage = i_path('pages/home-m.jpg')
end
```

Which in the view is rendered with help of a partial.

I now need to add similar functionality to render model attributes from a paperclip object.

Which is now looking like this:

```ruby
@respImage.push(
  {:breakpoint => 1024, 
   :src => slide.image.url(:desktop_reg),
   :src_2x => slide.image.url(:desktop_retina)}
)
@respImage.push(
  {:breakpoint => 768, 
   :src => slide.image.url(:tablet_reg),
   :src_2x => slide.image.url(:tablet_retina)}
)

#...
```

The final objective of Is to have a slideshow, with many slides.
A slide has several attribute strings and a paperclip attribute.
The paperclip attribute has 6 styles for each image size.

What is the standard mechanism in Rails to transmit data like the above to the view?
I'm assuming this generic array is not the most flexible solution.

---

This is where the code ended up.

**In the controller:**

```ruby
def home
  @mainImage2 = RespImage.new(:alt => 'default homepage image')

  @mainImage2.add_breakpoint(BREAKPOINTS['desktop'],i_path('pages/home-d.jpg'),i_path('pages/home-d_2x.jpg'));
  @mainImage2.add_breakpoint(BREAKPOINTS['tablet'],i_path('pages/home-t.jpg'),i_path('pages/home-t_2x.jpg'));
  #...
```

**models/resp_image.rb :**

```
class RespImage
  attr_accessor :alt, :breakpoints

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def add_breakpoint(px,src,src_2x)
    self.breakpoints ||= [];
    self.breakpoints.push RespBreakpoint.new(:px => px, :src => src, :src_2x =>src_2x)
  end

  def add_paperclip_breakpoints(paperclip)
    add_breakpoint(BREAKPOINTS('desktop'), paperclip.url(:desktop_reg), paperclip.url(:desktop_retina));
    add_breakpoint(BREAKPOINTS('tablet'), paperclip.url(:tablet_reg), paperclip.url(:tablet_retina));
    add_breakpoint(BREAKPOINTS('mobile'), paperclip.url(:mobile_reg), paperclip.url(:mobile_retina));
  end

  def default_src
    self.breakpoints.sort.first.src
  end
end
```

**models/resp_breakpoint**

```
class RespBreakpoint
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :px,:src,:src_2x

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def better_than?(other)
    self.px > other.px
  end

  def <=>(other)
    self.px <=> other.px
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self.px === other.px
  end
end
```

**Huge thanks to *@Dave Newton* below.**

Answer (score 1):

First, [use value objects](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/#value-objects). While an array of hashes seems easy at first, VOs can help encapsulate behavior as well as data easily, and improve readability.

Second, consider making those VOs "top-level" models such that they can be rendered using an appropriately-named partial, which I'm assuming would clean up your helper as well.

The last part of your question is a bit opaque without any context: what do you mean by "add similar functionality to render model attributes from a Paperclip object"? Do the objects have the same attributes? Is the data already represented by a class, or by attributes on a class?

If the latter, then you can use duck-typing to eliminate some of the duplication.

---

Right now it looks like this information is stored a bit funky. I'd probably turn the model around a bit and use a hash, keyed by breakpoint (useful since it's what CSS uses to trigger the style changes) or something more semantic (e.g., `:desktop`, `:tablet`, etc.).

Your model would contain the hash keys as attributes (i.e., `breakpoint`, `src`, and `src_2x`).

The values could be stored anywhere, it kind of depends on how often they'd need to change. It might be enough to use constants, or a YAML file, or a Ruby config object, etc.

The array itself would be created by a utility class or service object taking some parameter that determined what information needed to go in it. You might have a method that took something that returned either an `i_path` or slide image URL depending on what was passed in (think Inversion of Control).

Or it could be a decorator that decorated your slide model and a fake (or real) model for the `i_path` ones, etc.

Comment: I've added more details to the question.

Comment: Holy smokes, you helped so much. Thank you very much for your time. I'm super super pleased with the code, I'll paste above for posterity.  By the way, the view doesn't need distinction of the 3 breakpoints, so i left out the hash for breakpoints. The pixel value itself is the only required difference in the output loop. I"m using a responsive image JS polyfill to be exact.